How to get input from user for ad hoc manual runs in Snowpark
We have a small piece of code using snowpark using python to be run from inside snowflake. We need to get input from the user for ad hoc manual runs.
For example consider a code that takes start_date and end_date as input from the user. In normal scheduled runs it would be empty and would be calculated in the code. start_date will be current_date - 2 and end_date will be current_date - 1. In case we need to make an adhoc run for a specific date, the start_date and end_date would be the value from the user. For example consider start_date = 2024-12-01 and end_date = 2024-12-02.
I have tried input(), but the code seems to be running indefinitely.
In databricks I usually use widgets to get the input - how do I do it here?

In the ad-hoc run, you are running for 1 year vs. 1 day in the scheduled run. The ad-hoc run is expected to run longer. Can you check the query history for this run? Can you try running an ad-hoc run for a smaller timeframe, a day or so? Also, please add some code snippets for ad-hoc and normal run

I think the question may not be clear. The question is about How to get the adhoc input from the user in snowpark ? the date I mentioned was just an example - will update it if it is confusing...

Updated question for clarity...
